# Nested foreach in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to display data from the controller to view. I am able to display data from the first level of `@foreach( $item->name, $item->address, etc)` with ease. But I am having difficulty accessing a child of "subscriber_subscription" via Laravel blade convention. I tried accessing it using  via code below:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    ...
    @foreach($item->subscriber_subscription as $subs)
    ...
    ...
    @endforeach
    ...
    ...
@endforeach
```

JSON data used is:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Jollibee",
      "address":"31st cor. 9th Strata bldg. Ortigas Ave. Pasig City, 600",
      "contact":"87000",
      "email":"admin@jollibee.com.ph",
      "created_at":"2017-09-17 01:04:11",
      "updated_at":"2017-09-17 01:04:12",
      "subscriber_code":"jollibee",
      "subscriber_subscription":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "subscriber_id":1,
            "subscription_id":1,
            "start_date":"2017-09-17 01:35:27",
            "end_date":"2018-09-17 01:35:27",
            "created_at":"2017-09-17 01:35:23",
            "updated_at":"2017-09-17 01:35:23"
         },
         {  
            "id":6,
            "subscriber_id":1,
            "subscription_id":1,
            "start_date":"2017-10-17 01:35:27",
            "end_date":"2018-10-17 01:35:27",
            "created_at":"2017-09-17 01:35:23",
            "updated_at":"2017-09-17 01:35:23"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Bench",
      "address":"2207 Tektite Bldg. Ortigas Ave. Pasig City, 1600",
      "contact":"+639171234567",
      "email":"admin@benchtm.com.ph",
      "created_at":"2017-09-17 01:47:10",
      "updated_at":"2017-09-17 01:47:11",
      "subscriber_code":"bench",
      "subscriber_subscription":[  
         {  
            "id":4,
            "subscriber_id":2,
            "subscription_id":1,
            "start_date":"2017-09-17 14:19:15",
            "end_date":"2018-09-17 14:19:16",
            "created_at":"2017-09-17 14:19:20",
            "updated_at":"2017-09-17 14:19:20"
         },
         {  
            "id":5,
            "subscriber_id":2,
            "subscription_id":2,
            "start_date":"2017-09-17 14:19:15",
            "end_date":"2018-09-17 14:19:16",
            "created_at":"2017-09-17 14:19:20",
            "updated_at":"2017-09-17 14:19:20"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm getting this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Any help will be appreciated. Peace :-)

Thanks

Comment: you need to decode your json before `for loop` json_decode($items)

Comment: can you try accessing element as an array instead of the object like this `@foreach($item['subscriber_subscription']`

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik he used json format data in `for` so these will not help

Comment: I think he only showing us data as JSON but he is using model as i can see attribute.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik - tried this  @foreach($item['subscriber_subscription'] as $subs) but it still didn't work

Comment: are you using relation for `subscriber_subscription` if yes can you show us how you made relation

Comment: @AjayKumar - yes, I am using model.

Comment: so you need to use `$item['subscriber_subscription']` there is something wrong in you relation with model

Comment: the relation is as such - $items = Subscriber::with('SubscriberSubscription')->get();

Comment: what relation are you using `hasOne` or `hasMany`

Comment: Subscriber hasMany SubscriberSubscription

Comment: are you sure you don't have a typo of `$items` to `$item`?

Comment: what attribute you want to access from `$item->subscriber_subscription`

Comment: subscription_id,start_date, end_date

Comment: @MammaMia - yes I'm sure there's no typo

Comment: try to `dd($item->subscriber_subscription)` if you are getting collection of data then you can access otherwise there is no data collection is empty so check it first

Comment: @AjayKumar - sorry, but how can I check? the json I posted above is what I get whe I return $item in my controller

Comment: I've solved it. Apparently, i have to use $item->SubscriberSubscription which is the name of my model.

Comment: in controller after `$item` make a new line : `dd($items[0]->subscriber_subscription)` before `view(...)`

Comment: i think you made wrong relation it should be `public function subscriberSubscription(){ return $this->hasMany(...) }` then you can access `subscriber_subscription` if attribute don't exist then it shows null

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Apparently, i have to use $item->SubscriberSubscription which is the name of my model